# When I take a photo my "error" toast is displayed directly, why is the file not being created?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm asking a new question, if it already exists, please excuse me I searched again and again but I didn't find anything.

My code works perfectly on the API28 emulator but as soon as I run it on the API29 emulator and above, it doesn't work...

Can you help me ?

**CameraUtils.java**

```
public static File getNewFile() {
   
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "Failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;

        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

**CameraFragment.java**
I only show you the "btnTakePicture.setOnCLick....

```
btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
                AnimUtils.animateBtnTakePhoto(btnTakePicture);

                File file = CameraUtils.getNewFile();

                ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions =
                        new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();

                imageCapture.setTargetRotation(CameraUtils.getDisplayRotation(requireContext()));
                imageCapture.setFlashMode(flashMode);
                imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()),
                        new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                            @Override
                            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(requireContext(),
                                        new String[]{file.toString()}, null, null);

                                btnTakePicture.setEnabled(true);

                                switch (typeAction) {
                                    case CameraFragment.ACTION_MESSAGE:
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), PhotoMessageActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra(PhotoMessageActivity.IMG_URI, file.getPath());
                                        intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.UID, uidReceiver);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        break;
                                    case CameraFragment.ACTION_STATUS:
                                        startActivity(new Intent(requireContext(), AddNewStoryPhotoActivity.class)
                                        .putExtra("IMG_URI", file.getPath()));
                                        break;
                                    case CameraFragment.ACTION_UPDATE_PICTURE:
                                        CropImage.cropMiniatureFromFragment(Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getPath())),
                                                requireContext(), CameraFragment.this);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                                btnTakePicture.setEnabled(true);
                                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error taking photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

My code works with API 29 emulators, but as soon as my code is tested on an API29 and API30 emulator it no longer works.

Comment: `Can you help me ?` even better, learn how to help yourself :) `"Error taking photo"` isn't very useful to you as a developer to help debug the error, that's what exceptions are for. you need to be logging whatever `ImageCaptureException` is saying so that you can see what the exception actually is, you can do this by printing the exceptions message or by print the stack trace for it. once you know what the exception is, it becomes very simple to do research on what the error means and how to fix it, most likely it's going to lead you to a post of someone having the same problem previously

Comment: here is what it showed me:CameraErrorTaking : androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Failed to write temp file

Comment: Thank you !!! I managed to correct my mistake.